# how change right padding of select tag using tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

i want to change x padding of select tag, but the right padding not change. like the picture below

[image]

what i expected is like the picture below

[image]

here my code

```
<select class="border border-black/20 rounded-md px-3 py-2">
    <option selected>Choose City</option>
    <option>Jakarta</option>
    <option>Depok</option>
    <option>Surabaya</option>
</select>
```

i have using ::after but the content not showing.
here the code

```
<select class="border border-black/20 rounded-md px-3 py-2 appearance-none after:content-['▾'] after:text-black after:block">
    <option selected>Choose City</option>
    <option>Jakarta</option>
    <option>Depok</option>
    <option>Surabaya</option>
</select>
```

does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:: after does not work in select elements, so you must add a parent DIV tag and apply the CSS to that div tag.

Here is the code you can see.

```
<div class="border overflow-hidden flex items-center border-black/20 rounded-md 
block relative after::content-['\25BC'] after::absolute after::right-3 
after::pointer-events-none">
<select class="appearance-none w-full pl-3 py-2 pr-9">
<option selected>Choose City</option>
<option>Jakarta</option>
<option>Depok</option>
<option>Surabaya</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: it works thank you. but to write a pseudo-element in tailwind, it only take one colon

Comment: do you know the reason why in select elements :: after does not work ? or maybe you can give me an article / blog if you know

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a width-issue. Your padding is applied, but the dynamic width of your element doesn't change. So there is a padding, but you have to extend the width of the whole object.

Also the chevron is an ::after object and you will have to move it left with some padding to achieve the look you want.

Comment: i set the width, longer than before but not work, still like the picture and the ::after content still not showing after i add padding

Comment: You should add the padding to the cevron. You can always just add one ::after element. Since the chevron is added after your ::after-element, it will overwrite your ::after element. 

Did you try using the dev tools? There you can access the css and adjust it. It will be displayed in your browser realtime and by this, you can find what you have to edit to achieve your look.

Comment: like this ? class="border border-black/20 rounded-md px-3 py-2 after:px-10", but nothing has changed.

i not find ::after for select tag in dev tools, the ::after for select tag is in "styles" section isn't?

btw thanks for your response